# Django Integrity Error 1048 cannot be null

Tags: python, django, django-models

Under views.py

```
def addcomments(request):
    comment_text = request.POST.get('comment')
    user_id = request.POST.get('user_id')
    name = request.POST.get('name')
    email = request.POST.get('email')
    
    comment = Comment.objects.create(user_id=user_id, body=comment_text, name=name, email=email)
    comment.save()
    return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('users:detail', args=(user_id, )))
```

this one, from detail.html

```
{% extends 'base.html' %}

{% block title %}
    {{ user.user_fname }} {{ user.user_lname }}
{% endblock %}

{% block content %}

{% if error_message %}
    <p class="alert alert-danger">
        <strong>{{error_message}}</strong>
    </p>
{% endif %}


<div class="row">

    <div class="col-lg-6">
        <div class="mb-5">
            <h1>{{ user.user_fname }} {{ user.user_lname }}</h1>
            <p class="text-muted">{{ user.user_email }}</p>
            <p>Position: {{ user.user_position }}</p>
        </div>
        
        <div class="img-responsive">
            <img src="/users/media/{{user.user_image}}" alt="profile_user" class="img-rounded" width="300">
            <!-- ito yung hinahanap ng search engine-->
        </div>
        
        <div class="btn-group mt-5">

            <a href="{% url 'users:delete' user.id %}" class="btn btn-sm btn-danger">Delete</a>
            <a href="{% url 'users:edit' user.id %}" class="btn btn-sm btn-info">Edit</a>
            <a href="{% url 'users:index'%}" class="btn btn-sm btn-success">Back</a>
    
        </div>  
    </div>
        
    <div class="col-lg-6">
        <h2>Comment</h2>
        <p class="text-muted"> Number of comment : {{ comments_count }}</p>
        {% if comments_count > 0 %}
            {% for comment in comments %}
                {% if comment.active %}
                <p><strong>{{comment.name}}</strong> : {{comment.body}}</p>
                {% endif %}

            {% endfor %}
        {% endif %}

        <hr>
        <br><br><br><br><br><br>

        <form action="{%url 'users:addcomments'%}" method="post">
            
            {% csrf_token %}
            <div class="form-group">
                <label>Comment</label>
                <textarea name="comment" id="comment" cols="30" rows="5" class="form-control" required placeholder="Enter your comment here ..."></textarea>
            </div>
            
            <br>
            <input type="text" name="name" id="name" value="{{ user.user_lname }}">
            <input type="text" name="lname" id="lname" value="{{ user.user_fname }}">
            <input type="text" name="email" id="email" value="{{ user.user_email }}">
            <br><br><br><br>
            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-sm btn-primary">Add Comment</button>
        </form>
    </div>
</div>


{% endblock %}
```

this one for url.py

```
path('addcomments', views.addcomments, name='addcomments'),
```

I am having the error message,

**IntegrityError at /users/addcomments
(1048, "Column 'user_id' cannot be null")**

**During handling of the above exception ((1048, "Column 'user_id' cannot be null")), another exception occurred:**

from 404
users\views.py, line 146, in addcomments
comment = Comment.objects.create(user_id=users_id, body=comment_text, name=name, email=email) …
Local vars
Variable    Value
comment_text
'wwerwr'
email
'HeavyRain@gmail.com'
name
'Heavy'
request
<WSGIRequest: POST '/users/addcomments'>
user_id
None

the heavyrain details, ignore it, was trying stuffs

**this one for detail** detail is working fine properly, detail is on left side of the page, while addcomments is on the right side of the same page

```
@login_required(login_url='/users/login')
def detail(request, profile_id):
    try:
        user = User.objects.get(pk=profile_id)
        comments = Comment.objects.filter(user_id=profile_id)
        comments_count = Comment.objects.filter(user_id=profile_id).count()
    except User.DoesNotExist:
        raise Http404("Profile does not exist")
    return render(request, 'UI/detail.html', {'user': user, 'comments': comments, 'comments_count': comments_count})
```

Comment: Also `create` method doesn't require `save` method to be called.

Comment: Please can you post the `Comment` model

Comment: Please edit your question to add more code, rather than adding it as a comment, the formatting is lost

Comment: Also, the problem with your code is as per Hack3r's answer. You aren't providing a user ID for the comment so it raises an error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't have an `user_id` field in your html form that's why it becomes `None` or `null` and since you don't allow your user_id to be none (don't allow it to be none) django fails to create it. I suggest you get rid of the `user_id` in the creation and search for a user with that exact unique username that posted the form with

```py
user = request.user
comment = Comment.objects.create(user=user, body=comment_text, name=name, email=email)
```

Comment: I am calling it from my db
user.id in html file, it appears with this {{ user.id }}

somehow it can't be found on the views.py, I don't know whats the right

Answer (score 1):

I'm sorry but use a model form. It's the MOST appropriate solution. It will manage rendering your form in html and ensuring data is clean and validated.

```
from django import forms

class CommentForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Comment
        fields = [...]
```

Please see further information in the documentation.

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/topics/forms/modelforms/

Comment: I don't know about this yet, but I'll read them, right now, I am still new with django

Comment: No problems. I would try to advise you of best practices in any case.

Comment: my detail function is on the same page with the addcomments

detail function is okay, but add comments does not, I just don't know how to trace properly

Comment: Did you get to the bottom of this?

Comment: Its okay now, like hacker said,I've also rebuild it, and created new db.